# How to spoof the IP address in a UDP packet with scapy

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, scapy

I'm testing the security infrastructure on my server, running an application that accepts UDP traffic on port 7777. In order to do that, I want to send UDP packets to query for information about the application, but using a spoofed IP source.

Here is the packet I'm trying to send:

[image]

I've tried doing this with scapy, but it looks like the packet is not received on the other side, where I have tcpdump listening for UDP packets on port 7777.

This is the code I've tried:

```
from scapy.all import *
import random

D = 7777 # destination port
opcode = 'd'
target_ip = "1.1.1.1"
ips = target_ip.split('.'); # Target IP

payload = "SAMP{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}".format(chr(int(ips[0])), chr(int(ips[1])), chr(int(ips[2])), chr(int(ips[3])), chr(D & 0xFF), chr(D » 8 & 0xFF), opcode)

ip1 = 84
ip2 = random.randint(1,255)
ip3 = random.randint(1,255)
ip4 = random.randint(1,255)

A = str(ip1) + "." + str(ip2) + "." + str(ip3) + "." + str(ip4)

send(IP(src=A, dst=target_ip)/UDP(dport=D)/Raw(load=payload))
```

When I run, it says "Sent 1 packet", however I cannot see the packets in the other side when using tcpdump like this:

```
tcpdump -t -n -v -B 99999 -i gre1 -XX udp dst port 7777
```

I've tried with two different target IPs, both have port 7777 opened.

> The payload I want to send is basically 53 41 4D 50 C0 A8 C8 67 61 1E
> 69, from a spoofed IP src.

Comment: "but using a spoofed IP source" - to what end?

Comment: It is possible that IP is receiving the packet, but UDP is dropping the datagram because you have not properly calculated the (optional for IPv4) checksum using the spoofed IPv4 address. If you do not want to use the checksum field, it must be set to all zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

FYI you could create a packet template, it will be much easier. Something like

```
class YourPacket(Packet):
    fields_desc = [
        StrFixedLenField("head", "SAMP", 4),
        IPField("ip", "0.0.0.0"),
        ShortField("port", 0),
        ByteField("opcode", 0)
    ]
```

Then make sure you are sending it on the correct interface. You can add `iface=...` to `send()`.

Demo:

```
>>> x = YourPacket(ip="192.168.200.103", port=7777, opcode=ord(b"i"))
>>> x
<YourPacket  ip=192.168.200.103 port=7777 opcode=105 |>
>>> hexdump(x)
0000  53 41 4D 50 C0 A8 C8 67 1E 61 69                 SAMP...g.ai
>>> send(IP()/UDP(dport=7777)/x)
```

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: @Tryhard3r Did you ever find a solution? Im in the same boat